# Failed to compile : React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level

Tags: reactjs

Im new on ReactJS. Im trying to build up a cheat sheet ( ALL ON THE SAME PAGE ) to learn the basics.

My Props.js & PropsList.js are not working, I don't understand that error message.

PropList.js is the child of Prop.js and,
Prop.js is the child of App.js.

I'd just like to use useState ( in an easy way as a beginner ) all on the same page for the basic lessons ( useState, useEffect, props, etc .. ) and have a well sorted file.

Thanks in advance if you have any advice/suggestion.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import OutputtingLists from './Components/OutputtingLists';
import Props from './Components/Props';
import UsingState from './Components/UseState';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UsingState />
      <OutputtingLists />
      <Props/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**OutputtingLists.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const OutputtingLists = () => {

  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([
    { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'mario', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Welcome Party !', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'luigi', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Cheat sheet /ReactJS', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'peach', id: 3 },
  ])

  return (
    <div className="OutputtingLists"> 
      <h3> 3 : Outputting Lists</h3> 
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}> 
          <h5><u>{blog.title}</u></h5>
          <p>Written by par {blog.author}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default OutputtingLists;
```

**Props.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import PropsList from './PropsList';

const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([
    { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'mario', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Welcome Party !', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'luigi', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Cheat sheet /ReactJS', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'peach', id: 3 },
  ])

const Props = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> 4 : Props </h3>
      <PropsList blogs={blogs}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Props;
```

**PropsList.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const PropsList = (props) => {
  const blogs = props.blogs;
  const timbres = props.timbres;

  console.log(blogs, props)

  return (
    <div className="props-list">
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div className="props-list-preview" key={blog.id}> 
          <h5><u>{blog.title}</u></h5>
          <p>Written by par {blog.author}</p>
        </div>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
};

export default PropsList;
```

**Full Error Message**

```
Failed to compile.

src/Components/Props.js
 Line 5:27:   React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
 Line 11:31:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `Props` component. Move the `useState` hook ***into*** the component. React hooks can only be called from the body of function components and custom React hooks.

[Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

[image]

"Top-Level" here means at the top-level of the function component, not the top-level of the file defining it.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import PropsList from './PropsList';

const Props = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([
    { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'mario', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Welcome Party !', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'luigi', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Cheat sheet /ReactJS', body: 'lorem ipsum..', author:'peach', id: 3 },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3> 4 : Props </h3>
      <PropsList blogs={blogs}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Props;
```